# What is the current support for the W3C Geolocation API?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps

I'm looking to create a "check in" feature on my website for use by users with mobile devices.

What is the current state of support for the W3C Geolocation API specification?

Will it work on Androids/iPhones/Blackberrys?

Further, is there a better Geolocation tool that is more appropriate for mobile devices than the W3C spec? (Remember, this is not a native mobile app, it's a website)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3C geolocation API is part of many browsers today.
You can use it with iOS (v 3.0 +), Android (2.2 +) and BlackBerry.

You can find more information here: http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/wiki/SupportedPlatforms

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your answer.